# Google Maps by Address not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have two scripts.  One that will activate when a state / county drop down is changed it would do an address lookup and go to that particular county.  The second script I have populates Longitude and Latitude textboxes in a form.  I am trying to combine the two.  The latter script was using a static longitude/latitude and I need it to use an address like  I was using in the first script.  In trying to combine the two, I have an error in my code somewhere.  The map will not even appear.

```
function selectState(state_id){
     if(state_id!="-1"){
      loadData('city',state_id);
var e = document.getElementById("state");
var stateloc = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

   var sAddress = state_id + stateloc;

    var $latitude = document.getElementById('latitude');
    var $longitude = document.getElementById('longitude');
    //var latitude = 33.00636021320537
   // var longitude = -93.46687316894531;
    var zoom = 12;
    var geocoder;

    //var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': sAddress}, function(results, status)
{
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
    {


    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);



var mapOptions = {
  zoom: zoom,
  //center: LatLng,
  panControl: false,
  zoomControl: true,
  scaleControl: true,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}  

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 // position: LatLng,
 position: results[0].geometry.location,
  map: map,
  title: 'Drag Me!',
  draggable: true
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(marker){
  var latLng = marker.latLng;
  $latitude.value = latLng.lat();
  $longitude.value = latLng.lng();
});




//end geocoder check
        }
    else
    {
            alert("Geocode was not successful: " + status);
    }

    });




     }else{
       $("#city_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select city</option>");
     }
   }
```

html

```
<li>
    <label for="lat">Latitude:</label>
    <input id="latitude" placeholder="latitude" name="lat" type="text" class="text" />
</li>
<li>
    <label for="lon">Longitude:</label>
    <input id="longitude" placeholder="longitude" name="lon" class="text" type="text"/>
</li>

   <div id="map" style="width: 460px; height: 350px;"></div>
```

Comment: There is no map in your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set center of undefined map. So if everything other is ok you have to change this part:

```
       ...
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            // map is undefined here
            // map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: zoom,
                // center could be set here
                center: results[0].geometry.location,
                panControl: false,
                zoomControl: true,
                scaleControl: true,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }  

            // map is created here
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions);
            ...
```

Comment: I commented out map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);  Now I get a blank grey square in place of where the map displays.  Am I defining the map in the wrong location in the code?

Comment: Am I headed in the right direction?  What do I need to do?  Should I define a map or have I defined one already? Thanks.

Comment: Your map will be "grey" (uninitialized), if you haven't set the center and zoom when it exists.  You can do that either when you create the map (in the mapOptions used to create it), or at some point later (after it has been created), using setCenter and setZoom.